# R - Display NA counts in pie-chart

Tags: r, pie-chart

I have the following data set (`counts`):

```
  Letter Freq
     A  711
     B  542
     C 1268
     D  134
     E   11
     F  860
     G  745
   <NA> 1135
```

I want to represent those counts with a pie-chart. 
This is what I did:

```
countfrq <- ggplot(counts, aes(x="", y=Freq, fill=Letter)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
countfrq + coord_polar("y", start=0) + 
    labs(x="",y="", fill="Title") +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_fill_manual(labels=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","Missing"), values=c("#D73027" ,"#F46D43" ,"#FDAE61" ,"#FEE08B", "#D9EF8B", "#A6D96A", "#66BD63", "#1A9850")) + theme(panel.grid=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),legend.title=element_text(hjust=0.5,face="bold",size=16),legend.text=element_text(size=14))
```

This is what I obtain:

[image]

Since I didn't use white as a colour it confirms that the part representing the missing values (NA) is missing. What could I change in my code or data frame to include also the missing data?

Comment: Instead of supplying a new vector to `labels`, just recode `df$Letter` itself and supply `Letter` as the value to the `labels` argument. . You can do this with `df$Letter[is.na(df$Letter)] <- "Missing"`.

Comment: @seeellayewhy Thank you for your answer. When I try to do this I get the following warning and the change isn't made: `Warning message: In [<-.factor(*tmp*, is.na(counts$Letter), value = c(1L,  : invalid factor level, NA generated`. I don't understand why...

Comment: check out my answer. If it helped you solve the problem I'd appreciate a check and a vote!

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with it being a factor variable that spit out the same error so I converted `counts$Letter` to a character class. Let's first reproduce the problem:

```
library(ggplot2)
counts <- data.frame(Letter = c(LETTERS[1:7], NA),
                     Freq = c(711, 542, 168, 124, 11, 860, 745, 1135))
cols8 <- c("#D73027" ,"#F46D43" ,"#FDAE61" ,"#FEE08B", "#D9EF8B", "#A6D96A", "#66BD63", "#1A9850")

ggplot(counts, aes(x="", y=Freq, fill=Letter)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) + 
  labs(x="",y="",  fill="Title") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cols8) + 
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        legend.title=element_text(hjust=0.5,face="bold",size=16),
        legend.text=element_text(size=14))
```

[image]

Now to fix it becoming white, we'll just recode the NA to have some value. Remember to also convert to character class because factors don't store NA as a unique level.

```
counts$Letter <- as.character(counts$Letter)
counts$Letter[is.na(counts$Letter)] <- "Missing"

ggplot(counts, aes(x="", y=Freq, fill=Letter)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) + 
  labs(x="",y="",  fill="Title") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cols8) + 
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        legend.title=element_text(hjust=0.5,face="bold",size=16),
        legend.text=element_text(size=14))
```

[image]